# Fixed label in that position and equal width

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

When I was setting a **label** to **equal width** inside a **scrollview**, the label goes up to top instead of staying at the original position. When I remove the constraint, the label is back to position, but without the constraint, the label is not responsive to the screen size.

I already set the scroll view responsive to the view controller. I wished to know the idea of **fixing the label position and change the size accordingly to screensize**.

Comment: Apply only left align, right align, and center vertically or Top Constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Give constrains to your label: left align, right align and Center vertically to superview (in your case ScrollView).

Comment: Center horizontally is not needed if left align, right align Constraints are already used.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give frame. it will also work else :

Add a top, leading and trailing constraint to the label.

Top constraint will be responsible for your issue of moving to top and left, right constraint will take care of your width of label.